# Godot Mono : GetChild by name

Tags: mono, godot

**Some context :**

In Godot, one is constantly working with nodes and those nodes' children.

Godot has made the design choice of letting the dev manipulate nodes with some sort of **querying** language that often relies on the full path (starting from the root of the current scene).

For example if the scene is structured like this :

```
MyRootNode
  |
  |-- MyChild1
  |      |
  |      |-- MySubChild1
  |
  |
  |-- Mychild2
```

...then the devs are encouraged to access "MySubChild1" with a path :

```
node = get_node("MyRootNode/MyChild1/MySubChild1")
```

(note: I''m using the verbose "get_node" syntax rather than $ syntax for readability to C# devs)

Because of that ease of use, I can see that GDScript devs have a tendency to do this :

```
root = get_node("MyRootNode")
child1 = get_node("MyRootNode/MyChild1")
subchild1 = get_node("MyRootNode/MyChild1/MySubChild1")
```

...rather than this (pseudo-code) :

```
root = get_node("MyRootNode") 
child1 = root.get_child("MyChild1")
subchild1 = child1 .get_child("MySubChild1")
```

**It makes perfect sense to write queries in a weakly-typed scripting language :** all the queryable items have more or less the same type.

The *named* version of get_child() doesn't even exist. In reality you would need to do this :

```
root = get_node("MyRootNode")
child1 = root.get_child(0) // first child
subchild1 = child1 .get_child(0) // first child
```

=================

**This is all very awkward for a C# developer.** Because of the typing. It's like we're given safety but then it's instantly taken away.

Imagine this :

```
public class MyRootNode : Node
{

    private Control MyChild1 = null;  // initialized in _Ready once and for all

    public override void _Ready()
    {
        MyChild1  = GetNode<Control>("MyChild1");
    }

    public override void _Process(float delta)
    {
        // Not possible!!!
        var mySubChild1 = MyChild1.GetChild<TextureRect>("MySubChild1");
    }
}
```

**My question :** Is there a way of getting a child in a safe way? It seems to me that none of the solutions seem natural (as developed below), and I mean "safe" in contrast to that.

If I do this :

```
var mySubChild1 = GetNode<TextureRect>("MyRootNode/MyChild1/MySubChild1");
```

...then it's extremely unsafe in case of nodes renaming or if I decide to change the tree structure.

If I do this :

```
var mySubChild1 = MyChild1.GetChild<TextureRect>(0);
```

....then it's still horrendously unreadable (accessing named items by index? No thanks)

**As a C# dev, how do *you* do it?**

Comment: This seems like an open ended question. Anyway, getting nodes is not safe because the scene tree is external to your code. You might manipulate the scene (or have some other that does it) in such way that your code fails. Now, if you are in control of everything in your project, you can make sure the code your write won't fail. You might be interested in `get_node_or_null` (perhaps combined with a cast, and `is_instance_valid`), and also in Scene Unique Nodes. The reason get child by name wasn't approved is because get_node et.al. can provide that functionality.

Comment: It seems to me that you're not a C# developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question : It seems to me that there's no way of getting a child in a safe way. None of the solutions seem natural.

That is not a question. That is an statement of opinion.

---

> If I do this:
>
> ```
> var mySubChild1 = GetNode<TextureRect>("MyRootNode/MyChild1/MySubChild1");
> ```
>
> …then it's extremely unsafe in case of nodes renaming or if I decide to change the tree structure.

This is more unsafe that just a matter of changing the code. The problem is that the scene tree can change independently of the code. In my own terms: the scene tree is external to the code. And thus, the scene tree changing is a reason of change for the code. In other words, the scene tree changing is a *responsibility* of the code.

Remember single responsibility principle? That is how the software architects would suggest you deal with potential external changes. Make a piece of your code that is the only part that needs to change when the external change happens, so the change does not propagate across your code. *I would relax it and say that it does not have to be a separate class, it just has to be self-contained.*

In that order of ideas, this makes sense:

```
onready var root = get_node("MyRootNode")
onready var child1 = get_node("MyRootNode/MyChild1")
onready var subchild1 = get_node("MyRootNode/MyChild1/MySubChild1")
```

If you use these kind of declarations and initialization on top of your file, that is the only place where you would have to change the code to fix it. *Granted, you don't have `onready` in C#, instead you have to do it on `_Ready`.*

---

> If I do this:
>
> ```
> var mySubChild1 = MyChild1.GetChild<TextureRect>(0);
> ```
>
> … then it's still horrendously unreadable (accessing named items by index? No thanks)

Agreed. Then don't do it.

---

> As a C# dev, how do you do it?

I don't know what C# developers do. Because I'm not actively using C# at the time.

---

*Now, I did bring up a few other things in comments.*

**First**, if you are in control of the project, you can make sure your code does not fail. That of course might means changing the paths… However, if you use [Scene Unique Nodes](https://docs.godotengine.org/cs/stable/tutorials/scripting/scene_unique_nodes.html) you can minimize it.

This code:

```
onready var root = get_node("MyRootNode")
onready var child1 = get_node("MyRootNode/MyChild1")
onready var subchild1 = get_node("MyRootNode/MyChild1/MySubChild1")
```

Would turn into this:

```
onready var root = get_node("%MyRootNode")
onready var child1 = get_node("%MyChild1")
onready var subchild1 = get_node("%MySubChild1")
```

That is, the scene tree hierarchy is no longer relevant. And given that you give good names to your `Node`s, you should be able to move them around in your scene tree without further issue. And to be clear, this is implemented in the `get_node` function so other languages such as C# can use (and GDScript gets some syntactic sugar on top, which I'm not using here).

So yes, you can do that in C#:

```
    private Control MyChild1 = null;

    public override void _Ready()
    {
        MyChild1 = GetNode<Control>("%MyChild1");
    }
```

---

**Second**, you can use `get_node_or_null` (`GetNodeOrNull` in C#). So your code does not throw when there isn't a node. Instead you can handle the null.

Speaking of nulls. When a `Node` is freed (e.g. by calling `queue_free`, which is `QueueFree` in C#) it does not make the references to it null. *And no, Godot does not override the equality operators in C#.* Which is why we also have `is_instance_valid` (`Object.IsInstanceValid` in C#).

---

**Third**, the idea of getting a child by name is not needed in Godot because `get_node` et.al. can do it.

To be clear, `get_node` does not work from the root of the current scene, it works from the `Node` on which you call it. So you can do this:

```
public class MyRootNode : Node
{

    private Control MyChild1 = null;  // initialized in _Ready once and for all

    public override void _Ready()
    {
        MyChild1  = GetNode<Control>("MyChild1");
    }

    public override void _Process(float delta)
    {
        // Notice I'm using GetNode here
        var mySubChild1 = MyChild1.GetNode<TextureRect>("MySubChild1");
    }
}
```

I don't know if that is satisfactory for you, and I don't know if that is a common practice.

Comment: I think that you mostly addressed my issue by pointing me in the direction of the Godot devs philosophy. I want to try to use "%" more extensively for a little while and then I'll mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Someone else posted this answer in a different discussion channel : It provides extra elements, more centered around C#'s possibilities.

> if it’s **exported nodepaths** I highly recommend
> https://github.com/31/GodotOnReady it cuts down on a lot of
> boilerplate code.
>
> Otherwise **parentNode.GetNode(“path”)** has been working great.
>
> Using **%** in combination with ***"Access as Scene Unique Name"*** is
> cool with stuff that you will tweak and move around a lot, I use
> it with UI mostly.
>
> For additional safety, you can rock **parentNode.GetNodeOrNull(path)**.
> Unlike GetNode, GetNodeOrNull with a type won’t raise an Exception if
> something doesn't match (type or name), it just returns null.
> So at least it won’t silently burn you.
>
> Best practice I found is to **only use these methods in node setup**
> **methods.**
>
> Otherwise I do regular **dependency injection**, and **groups** to
> find what I need.
>
> That being said, I always advocate **failing loudly and failing fast,**
> so I only use GetNode and existing references. If it explodes
> it means I messed up.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what anyone does there are ways for it to break.  Some of the responsibility simply must fall on developers changing code to test their work.  If you wish to access something by name, then changing that name on the object but not at the point of access is going to cause failure.  That said, you can avoid the risk of reorganization of your object breaking your code by using the less-efficient

```
Node : find_node ( String mask, bool recursive=true, bool owned=true ) const
```

so

```
root = get_node("MyRootNode")
child1 = get_node("MyRootNode/MyChild1")
subchild1 = get_node("MyRootNode/MyChild1/MySubChild1")
```

can become

```
root = find_node("MyRootNode")
child1 = find_node("MyChild1")
subchild1 = find_node("MySubChild1")
```

It requires you to name your nodes of interest uniquely within this object.  But the structure to traverse to reach said nodes can change.